# How do I get PyCharm to help me with parameters as much as Brackets does?

Tags: angularjs, pycharm

When I type Angular code into Brackets, I get a lot of help with what parameters I should input into functions.

[image]

But at work I need to use PyCharm. Can I get PyCharm to provide this kind of help as well? As it is now, in my PyCharm installation, I get none of this help for AngularJS.

Comment: If you mean Angular1 (and therefore, not Angular2 with TypeScript), then you likely need to install the DefinitelyType'd community type bindings which give PyCharm/WebStorm the extra information for hinting. The [WebStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html) applies to PyCharm as well.